# passport.js user data not being stored

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I've been banging my head on the keyboard with this for 10 hours now.
I have a simple local-login nodejs script, and it seems to only work only once.

Here's my code.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

var sessionOpts = {
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({'db':'sessions'}),
    secret: sessionSecret,
    cookie : { httpOnly: true, secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}
}

app.use(cookieParser(sessionSecret)); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(session(sessionOpts)); // session secret

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

The serialize and deserialize functions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

    //console.log(user._id) - This is working
    done(null, user._id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

    //console.log(user.) - This is working
    var ident = id.toString();

    db.accounts.findOne({'_id':ObjectId(ident)}, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

The local-login function:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        db.accounts.findOne({'email':email}, function(err, user){


            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, {'msg':'user not found'});

            if (!validPassword(password, user.pass))
                return done(null, false, {'msg':'incorrect password'}); 

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

}));
```

Login:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    failureRedirect : '/login'}),
        function(req, res){

            res.redirect('/profile');      

        });  

});
```

The authentication check:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){

        return next();
    }
    else{

        console.log('failed'); 
    }
}
```

using it:

```
app.get('/authenticate', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){

    console.log('FINALLY!!');


});
```

This is what I can see happening when I debug some things:

1. When I log in with my form the email and password are passed through, it's finding the user in the database and the password matches.
2. It's redirected to the profile page no problem. If I enter the wrong email or password, I get the proper failure messages respectively.
3. When I try to get to the /authenticate page. It always fails.

So I looked into my session store, and this is what I see:

```
    "_id" : "XJiIfjjTtODchUM5Dt-J9BAVM6rDa6Ly",
    "session" : {
            "cookie" : {
                    "path" : "/",
                    "_expires" : ISODate("2015-06-19T08:33:15.304Z"),
                    "originalMaxAge" : 14400000,
                    "httpOnly" : true,
                    "secure" : false,
                    "expires" : ISODate("2015-06-19T08:33:15.304Z"),
                    "maxAge" : 14399999,
                    "data" : {
                            "originalMaxAge" : 14400000,
                            "expires" : ISODate("2015-06-19T08:33:15.304Z"),
                            "secure" : false,
                            "httpOnly" : true,
                            "domain" : null,
                            "path" : "/"
                    }
            },
            "passport" : {

            }
    },
    "expires" : ISODate("2015-06-19T08:33:15.304Z")
```

Also, when I `console.log(req.user)`, it always undefined.

So somewhere along the way the session data isn't getting passed to the express or passport session store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.accounts.findById(id, function(err, user){
       return done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Please try this code, it works for me, you can see here:
https://github.com/wangyangkobe/wangqiuke/blob/master/config/passport.js

For the second problem, pleae change code

```
var sessionOpts = {
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({'db':'sessions'}),
    secret: sessionSecret,
    cookie : { httpOnly: true, secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}
}
```

to

```
var sessionOpts = {
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({'db':'sessions'}),
    secret: sessionSecret,
    cookie : { httpOnly: true, secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}
}
```

From the document:

> **saveUninitialized**
>
> Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A
> session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified. **Choosing
> false is useful for implementing login sessions, reducing server
> storage usage, or complying with laws that require permission before
> setting a cookie.** Choosing false will also help with race conditions
> where a client makes multiple parallel requests without a session.

Comment: Hey, thanks brother. This did help, as now the req.user is being set. Secondary problem is that I found out that each time a user logs in, 4 sessions are being created in the database. the first one is good, the following 3 are empty.

Comment: please change another user, try again. for every user, there is only on stored record.

Comment: Thank you so much. Should have asked this question 10 hours ago, would have saved a ton of time knowing that all I needed to do was 'return' then done function. lol